# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im making a simple java script game and when I load up my html file to google chrome I get a "uncaught syntexerror: unexpected end of input" and it says the error code is on line 143 This is the function that is on line 143 "

```
function colorText(showWords, textX,textY, fillColor) {       
    canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;     
    canvasContext.fillText(showWords, textX,textY); 
}
```

Comment: That function by itself is valid syntax. Just go ahead and try pasting it into the javascript console in your browser. If it were invalid, the console would yell at you. Chances are you have a syntax error somewhere on either side of the function, perhaps a missing parenthesis or curly bracket?

Comment: Comment out chunks of code until you do not see the error or use a tool like jshint or jslint.

Answer (score 1):

You must look else where. This error is the result of a missing or extra `{` or `}` that is above the line the error occurred.